# Scrapy Simple Rule Doesn't Follow Links

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a very simple Scrapy `CrawlSpider` and I have given it a simple rule "Crawl/Follow any link that contains '/search/listings'". But the spider is not crawling/following any of these links?

I have confirmed that the start url contains many links with the href '/search/listings' so the links are there.

Any idea whats going wrong?

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "MySpider"
    allowed_domains = ["mywebsite.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mywebsite.com/results"]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/search/listings(.*)']), callback="parse2")]

    def parse2(self, response):

        # This function is never called
        log.start("log.txt")
        log.msg("Page crawled: " + response.url)
```

The start url "http://www.mywebsite.com/results" contains these links that I want the rule to apply to:

```
<a href='/search/listings?clue=healthcare&amp;eventType=sort&amp;p=2' class='button button-pagination' data-page='2' >2</a> 
<a href='/search/listings?clue=healthcare&amp;eventType=sort&amp;p=3' class='button button-pagination' data-page='3' >3</a> 
<a href='/search/listings?clue=healthcare&amp;eventType=sort&amp;p=4' class='button button-pagination' data-page='4' >4</a>
```

Comment: I suggest you debug it using the shell. Run `scrapy shell http://www.mywebsite.com/results`, then try the link extractor in the shell: import the class first and then run the extractor with: `LinkExtractor(allow=['/search/listings(.*)']).extract_links(response)`. This should help to see what's going on.

Comment: @elias Thanks for the comment. I've followed your steps and it prints a list `[Link(url='A', text='2', fragment='', nofollow=False),Link(url='B', text='2', fragment='', nofollow=False),Link(url='D', text='2', fragment='', nofollow=False),]`. I've abrieviated the links down to A, B, D for brevity. I think I can conclude from this that its finding the links but not calling the callback? Any advice?

Comment: Hmmm, what if it is calling the callback, but that log stuff isn't working for some reason? Can you try logging with `self.log('message here')` and checking out the output of running the spider?

Comment: if you could provide the actual start-url it will be very easy to debug.